# Vue Websockets double

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, websocket

I have some problems using Laravel/Echo websockets with Vue.js.
I have everything setup as needed, and it works, but not as expected.
So the problem is that, when I refresh the page and send request it will show that request, but if I change a page and return to that page where is that websocket, it will double that request, and same will happen if I click on another route. Basically if I change page 5 times, it will show that websocket 5 times in that table, why is that?
Here is my setup.

This is mounted method where I'm connecting to the channel.

```
mounted() {
        if(this.liveData){
            window.Echo.channel("addOrder").listen(".order-created", (order) => {
                this.$store.commit("ADD_ORDER", order);
            });
        }
        
        this.$store.dispatch("GET_ORDERS");
    },
```

and here is my connection in main.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'some_key',
    wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
    wsPort: 6001,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Echo is attached to `window`, Vue is not reloading page, it's just switching it with JS, so your connection stills alive.

You should disconnect before leaving page, so just do it in `beforeDestroy` hook. More about hooks [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy)

Also if you need this connection everywhere you should not initialize it in `mounted`, `created` or elsewhere in Vue component, you can just create separate file or plugin for Vue, because that function will trigger each time you opening page.